# Estimate Quaternion from the Full Transformation matrix(4x4) with shear

Tags: math, matrix, itk

I have obtained a full transformation matrix (4x4) (the s form) and looks like this

```
array([[-4.10156250e-01,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 8.90400009e+01],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  4.11722958e-01, -7.76345863e-02, -1.59686249e+02],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  3.57474685e-02,  8.93157482e-01, -2.27202545e+02],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

The operations encoded in the transformation matrix are rotation, translation, scaling,  and shear. I want to calculate the proper 3x3 rotation matrix so that I can estimate the quaternions for the above matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how this is done in [BRAINSTools](https://github.com/BRAINSia/BRAINSTools/blob/v5.4.0/BRAINSCommonLib/ConvertToRigidAffine.h#L428-L486).